# Why I always get same error while trying to package a Python3 Kivy app to APK Android using Buildozer?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, apk, buildozer, panda3d

This is what I do on terminal for packing my Python3/Kivy app to APK:

```
buildozer init
```

and then:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

Everything goes fine until I get following error message:

```
from panda3d.core import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Developer/Panda3D/panda3d/core.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Developer/Panda3D/panda3d/core.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/Panda3D/panda3d/core.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/Panda3D/panda3d/core.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

P.s. it looks like issue is incompatibility between Panda3d and my M1 Mac